# cx_Freeze ImportError: No module named 'kivy-deps.gstreamer'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an exe file from my python code via cx_Freeze.
When I run my setup.py file (which you may check below), I get an error message telling:

> ImportError: No module named 'kivy-deps.gstreamer'

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

(kivy-deps.gstreamer is installed, I also re-installed it to be sure)

Thanks in advance...

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {"packages": ["kivy","pygame","kivy-deps.gstreamer"], "includes": ["PIL","wheel","setuptools",], "excludes": []}


base = None
#if sys.platform == "win32":
#    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name="guifoo",
    version="0.1",
    description="My GUI application!",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("test.py", base=base)],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `"kivy_deps.gstreamer"` (with underscore) instead of `"kivy-deps.gstreamer"` (with hyphen) in the `build_exe_options`.

The corresponding import statement would namely read

```
import kivy_deps.gstreamer
```

not

```
import kivy-deps.gstreamer
```

probably because in that second statement the hyphen would be interpreted as a subtraction operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm quite new to Python. That was helpful. I mark this as solved but in fact this was only a part of my problem. My main problem is that I get an "[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort." error while trying to run my compiled exe. I will create another question regarding this issue. I will be glad if you can also help me on that.